# TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

So I was trying to fix this thing for a few hours now, and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

This thing should execute itself when member joins the guild

```
const { Discord, MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js")

module.exports = {
    name: "guildMemberAdd",
     run: async ({bot, member}) => {
        const welcome = new MessageEmbed()
            .setDescription(`
<:nezuko_peek:974066160108732517> — New friend just showed up: <@${member.user.id}>

Welcome fellow adventurer in **Jasmine Dragon**! What brings you in these sides? <:girl_love:973968823449436190> Here, go to <#972618593294512128> to introduce yourself and talk with us in <#971800237507248158>!
`)
            .setImage("https://64.media.tumblr.com/01a9f72f062feaafa60cdbf80f9ba729/tumblr_inline_orgoyznIM51sd5e91_500.gif")
            .setColor("#F7DF79")
            .setFooter({ text: "Thank you for joining and enjoy your stay!" })

        member.guild.channels.cache.get("971800237507248158").send({ content: `<@&974343947105206382>`, embeds: [welcome] })
    }
}
```

Here's my event handler

```
const { getFiles } = require("../util/functions")

module.exports = (bot, reload) => {
    const {client} = bot

    let events = getFiles("./events/", ".js")

    if (events.length === 0){
        console.log("No events to load")
    }

    events.forEach((f, i) => {
        if (reload)
        delete require.cache[require.resolve(`../events/${f}`)]
        const event = require(`../events/${f}`)
        client.events.set(event.name, event)

        if (!reload)
        console.log (`${i + 1}. ${f} loaded`)

    })

    if (!reload)
    initEvents(bot)
}

function triggerEventHandler(bot, event, ...args){
    const {client} = bot
    
    try {
        if (client.events.has(event))
        client.events.get(event).run(bot, ...args)
        else
        throw new Error(`Event ${event} does not exist`)
    }
    catch(err){
        console.error(err)
    }
}

function initEvents(bot) {
    const {client} = bot
    
    client.on("ready", () => {
        triggerEventHandler(bot, "ready")
    })

    client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
        triggerEventHandler(bot, "messageCreate", message)
    })

    client.on("guildMemberAdd", () => {
        triggerEventHandler(bot, "guildMemberAdd")
    })
}
```

And here's my index.js

```
const Discord = require("discord.js")
require("dotenv").config()
const { MessageEmbed, MessageActionRow, MessageSelectMenu } = require("discord.js")

const slashcommands = require("./handlers/slashcommands")

const client = new Discord.Client({
    intents: [
        "GUILDS",
        "GUILD_MESSAGES",
        "GUILD_MEMBERS"
    ]
})

// Bot config
let bot = {
    client,
    prefix: "i?",
    owners: ["511889215672287242"]
}

// Handlers
client.commands = new Discord.Collection()
client.events = new Discord.Collection()
client.slashcommands = new Discord.Collection()

client.loadEvents = (bot, reload) => require("./handlers/events")(bot, reload)
client.loadCommands = (bot, reload) => require("./handlers/commands")(bot, reload)
client.loadSlashCommands = (bot, reload) => require("./handlers/slashcommands")(bot, reload)

client.loadEvents(bot, false)
client.loadCommands(bot, false)
client.loadSlashCommands(bot, false)

// Slash commands handler
client.on("interactionCreate", (interaction) => {
    if (!interaction.isCommand()) return
    if (!interaction.inGuild()) return interaction.reply("This command can only be used in a server")

    const slashcmd = client.slashcommands.get(interaction.commandName)

    if (!slashcmd) return interaction.reply("Invalid slash command")

    if (slashcmd.perm && !interaction.member.permissions.has(slashcmd.perm))
        return interaction.reply("You don not have permission for this command")

    slashcmd.run(client, interaction)
})

module.exports = bot

client.login(process.env.TOKEN)
```

Other events like "ready" and "messageCreate" are working just fine so I'm not sure why it's not working.

Comment: guildMemberJoin will return the user property already so just try `member.id`

Comment: yeah I tried that to member.id returns the same error 
<:nezuko_peek:974066160108732517> — New friend just showed up: <@${member.id}>
                                                                          ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Comment: what is the output if you just console log `member`?

Comment: undefined - thats all i get when logging it